# mysqli_select_db() not working properly ..?

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

```
function db_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) {
    $db_connect = mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die('Could not connect: ' . mysqli_error($db_connect));
    $db_select = mysqli_select_db($db_name, $db_connect) or die ('Could not select ' . $db_name . ': ' . mysqli_error($db_select));
}
```

Every variable is defined. All that appears is

> Could not select CMS:

There isn't even an error message. What am I doing wrong? As far as I am aware, it is connecting to MySQL, but it isn't connecting to the specified database 'CMS'.

Comment: It should be `....or die ('Could not select ' . $db_name . ': ' . mysqli_error($db_connect));`

Comment: That didn't really solve anything. Still not getting any errors and it's still not working properly either. I don't know why it's not connecting to the database.

Comment: FYI, `mysqli_connect` / the `mysqli` constructor will **NEVER** return a *falsey* value so you can forget about using `or die()` (which you should never use anyway). Also, you can pass the *dbname* parameter in as the fourth argument to `mysqli_connect()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to php.net, `mysqli_select_db` exepts to be first parameter `MYSQLI link`, seccond `DB Name`

```
bool mysqli_select_db ( mysqli $link , string $dbname )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.select-db.php

You should turn on error reporting for next time, to catch that error.

```
error_reporting(1);
```

Comment: Now it's saying `Could not select CMS: Access denied for user 'admin'@'localhost' to database 'CMS'`

Comment: Actually I just realized I somehow managed to accidentally remove the admin user from having privileges.

Comment: What is  mysqli $link ?

Comment: @KavinRajuS Handler returned by `mysqli_connect`.